# C# - Vsprintf equivilant?Converting Char to Int

Tags: c#, c

Using vsprintf, the c code below converts a char array to an int. How would I do this in c#? I have tried casting the c# string to an int, and then adding the values, but the return result is not the same. **My c# code needs to return the same value as the c code does(3224115)**

**C# Code**

```
  var  astring = "123";
        int output = 0;
        foreach(char c in astring){
            var currentChar = (int)c;
            output += c;
        }
//output = 150
```

**C Code**

```
void vout(char *string, char *fmt, ...);                                        
char fmt1 [] = "%d";                                                  

int main(void)                                                                  
{                                                                               
   char string[32];                                                            

   vout(string, fmt1, '123');        //output is 3224115                             
   printf("The string is:  %s\n", string);                                      
}                                                                               
void vout(char *string, char *fmt, ...)                                         

{                                                                               
   va_list arg_ptr;                                                             

   va_start(arg_ptr, fmt);                                                      
   vsprintf(string, fmt, arg_ptr);                                              
   va_end(arg_ptr);                                                             
}
```

Comment: You should post your c# attempt

Comment: `string.Format` or interpolated strings `$"{yourValue}"`

Comment: what problem are you attempting to solve.

Comment: Not valid C code.  Try compiling and re-post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out. Could be a bit cleaner, but it works, and gets the same output as the c code.

```
 public static ulong getAsciiLiteral(string x)
{
    int len = x.Length;
    string[] strArray = new string[32];
    byte[] finalByte = new byte[32];
    int i = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int i3 = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    var hexFinalString = "0x";
    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x);

    if(len >= 5)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (4 + i3 == len)
            {
                offset = i3;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i3++;
            }
        }

    }


    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        strArray[i] = b.ToString("X2");
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    i3 = 0;
    while (i3 < len - 1)
    {



        hexFinalString += strArray[offset];
        offset++;
        i3++;
    }


    var ret = Convert.ToUInt64(hexFinalString, 16);
    return ret;

}
```